# Read and write JSON file without changing formatting in PHP

Tags: php, json

Let's have a `file.json` containing a JSON, e.g.

```
{
  "first-key": "foo",
  "second-key": "bar"
}
```

Now if I encode and decode the JSON with PHP built-in functions, it changes the formatting. Is there a way how to do this without reformatting the JSON?

I need to add a single key and the file is committed in Git. Hence, I want to avoid changing lines that didn't really change.

Comment: `Without Chainging Formatting` Means??

Comment: Without changing indentation, line endings etc.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON_PRETTY_PRINT flag is as close as you're going to get without manually editing the json-encoded string. It looks like it should work for your example though.

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "first-key": "foo",
  "second-key": "bar"
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$arr['second-key'] = 'baz';

print_r(json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

=

```
{
    "first-key": "foo",
    "second-key": "baz"
}
```

Comment: I know about the flag. It still doesn't solve the problem. It reformats whole file by its rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json = '{
  "first-key": "foo",
  "second-key": "bar"
}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";

$arr_new = array("newKey"=>$arr);

$json_new = json_encode($arr_new);

echo $json_new;

?>
```